# Calling an overloaded function from a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

C++ newbie here.  Is there a way to call an overloaded function in a base class from the same function name with the same signature in a derived class?  In Smalltalk, I can do it the "super" keyword.  Is there any C++ equivalent?

```
class MyBaseClass {
  void initialize() { doSomething(); }
};

class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass {
  void initialize() {
      super initialize(); // first, call MyBaseClass::initialize()
      doLocalInitialize(); // now initialize non-inherited members
}
```

Thanks,
Norm

Comment: You already have it in your comment: `MyBaseClass::initialize();`

Comment: you also probably want to do the function `virtual` - not necessary, but looks like that way to me.

Answer (score 1):

You literally said the correct syntax in your comment  :)

```
class MyBaseClass {
    void initialize() { doSomething(); }
};

class MyDerivedClass : public MyBaseClass {
void initialize() {
    MyBaseClass::initialize(); // first, call MyBaseClass::initialize()
    doLocalInitialize(); // now initialize non-inherited members
}
```

Comment: Dang, it's that easy?  Thanks for the responses.